# Caculating masses of unstable particles

Tags: special-relativity, particle-physics, energy-conservation, particle-detectors

I learned that if an unstable particle $A$ decays to $N$ particles $i=1,2,3..N$ in the final state, i.e.
$$A \rightarrow 1 +2+...N,$$
then the invariant mass W of the final state particles is given by 
$$W^2c^4=(\sum E_i)^2-(\sum \vec{p_i})^2c^2=E_A^2-(\vec{p_A})^2c^2=m_A^2c^4. \tag{1}$$

So $m_A$ the rest mass of the unstable particle $A$ can be found.

The above equation says that $\sum E_i=E_A$ by conservation of energy, where $E=\gamma m c^2$.

But what if some of the $N$ particles are charged, attracts or repel each other and thus have additional energy on top of $E_i=\gamma_i m_ic^2$?

By conservation of energy, shouldn't it be $(\sum E_i) + electro static energy= E_A$ instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a good question, but the answer is ... really quite mundane.

It turns on this: how do you measure the $E_i$s and $\vec{p}_i$s that appear in Eqn. 1? Or a little more pointedly *where* do you measure them with practical instruments.

Generally the answer is that you measure them far (in particle physics temrs) from the actual decay site when they are surrounded by neutral matter (the detector itself if nothing else).

So, by the time you make the measurement all that electrostatic potential energy and latent force has *already been concerted to changes in the kinetic energy and momenta*. This conversion doen't affect the results because the electrostatic interaction is conservative.<sup>1</sup>

So, in principle you are right, but in practice this isn't something we need to bother ourselves about.

---

<sup>1</sup> Some of the interactions between the products and that neutral matter *may* affect the results. Modeling that so that you can correct for it is part of the job of simulation.